# What exactly is the return type of the printfn function in F#?

Tags: f#

I looked up the documentation of printfn [here](https://fsharp.github.io/fsharp-core-docs/reference/fsharp-core-extratopleveloperators.html) and this is what it says:

> printfn format
>
> Print to stdout using the given format, and add a newline.
>
> format : TextWriterFormat<'T> The formatter.
>
> Returns: 'T The formatted result.

But if I type the following in FSI

```
> let v = printfn "Hello";;
Hello
val v : unit = ()
```

it states that `v` (the return value of printfn) is of type `unit`.

This seems inconsistent, but I guess I am missing something here, so can anybody help me out ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not inconsistent. In your example, the format is of type `TextWriterFormat<unit>`, so the final return type is `unit`, because `'T` is `unit`.

If you had written `let v = printfn "Hello %s"`, then the type of `v` would be `string -> unit`. This is how F# provides type-safe string formatting.